# AlliedVision ALVIUM 1800 U-040c not showing as /dev/video0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, drivers

I have the camera in object connected through USB to my PC (Core i3 with Ubuntu 20.04).

`dmesg` shows me that the camera is correctly connected:

```
[    2.116714] usb 2-1.2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.124436] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    2.124713] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[    2.125241] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    2.128500] systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
[    2.137115] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1ab2, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.137122] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[    2.137126] usb 2-1.2: Product: ALVIUM 1800 U-040c
[    2.137129] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Allied Vision
[    2.137131] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 01NXC
```

as well as `lsusb`

```
~$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1ab2:0001  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 08bb:29c6 Texas Instruments PCM2906C Audio CODEC
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2513 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

From the producer [manual](https://cdn.graftek.com/system/files/16953/original/AVT_Alvium_User_Guide.pdf) it seems that a Linux driver for the camera is not needed (Section: Installing the camera/Software and Driver Installation on the Host/Required Components).

However I cannot see this camera in `/dev/video0` and if I launch [Cheese](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/cheese.1.html) no camera is detected!!!

Any idea on how to solve this issue?